# Paypal shipping and monthly reoccurring billing

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am going to set up a website that will use paypals reoccuring billing. The question I have is if I have over 3000 customers, for example, how do I make it more simple for me to print out their addresses where to ship the product instead of doing it one by one?
I am not going to use Paypal api for this but instead direct link to paypal as such described in this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHC9BoRDEOY&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to set something up like this, I would uses PayPal's IPN feature to record all of the transactions, transaction details and profile details for these recurring profiles in my database.  Then I would create my own system for running reports or a query against my Database, and then display the information in what ever format I would want.

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.

There is more on IPN [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples).